# how to return success message in session variaible using jquery.get() method

Tags: php, jquery

i m using `jQuery.get()` to delete row from a table from a page  `main.php`. now i want to show success message after deleting row ,that success message should be in session variable(`$_session['suxesMsg']`)

1. how do i set success message on a    session variable and show on specific span ?

or

2. is there any other method in jQuery that a message appear for 5-10
   seconds only and then disappear?

Here is my code

**main.php**

---

```
 <?php  if($_SESSION['suxesMsg']!='') { ?>
   <span class="msg">
     <?php echo $_SESSION['suxesMsg'];unset($_SESSION['suxesMsg']);  } ?>
   </span>

  <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" id="promotionTable">
   <tr>
      <td align="left"><img border='0' src='images/just.gif'/>First Promotion</td>
      <td align="center" >View Detail</td>
      <td align="center" id="deleteMe">
       <img src='images/delete.png' alt='Delete' width='14' height='14'id="45"/>
      </td>                
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"><img border='0' src='images/just.gif'/>First Promotion</td>
      <td align="center" >View Detail</td>
      <td align="center" id="deleteMe">
       <img src='images/delete.png' alt='Delete' width='14' height='14' id="48"/>
      </td>                
   </tr>
   </table>



<script type="text/javascript">        
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){      
        jQuery('#deleteMe img').click( function() {   
            if(!confirm('Want to delete!')) return; 
        jQuery.get('deleteThis.php', {oid:this.id});
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().fadeTo(400, 0, function() {
           jQuery(this).remove();
        });
    });
   </script>
```

**deleteThis.php**

---

```
if(isset($_GET[oid]))
    {
        $offerID=$_GET[oid];    
        $delsql="DELETE FROM some_table WHERE promotion_id=".$offerID;  
        $db->query($delsql);        
        $_SESSION['suxesMsg'] = "Promotion deleted sucessfully.";
    }
```

Thanks for helping me alwayz

Comment: as an aside, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol:  "Note that GET should not be used for operations that cause side-effects, such as using it for taking actions in web applications. One reason for this is that GET may be used arbitrarily by robots or crawlers, which should not need to consider the side effects that a request should cause."

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but i need solution sir

Comment: @I Like PHP: Sorry, a solution to my comment is to use POST for operations which cause side effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why it needs to go into the session. Looking at your code this would mean you need to refresh the page before the actual error message is shown, because it is done in PHP when the page is originally generated.

Could you not return a success message directly in the request which deleted the item, and then show it immediately using javascript? You could use JSON to encode a success flag and a string message which is sent back. For example something like this:

```
//make post request to delete item
$.post'deleteThis.php', {oid:this.id}, function(data) {
    if (data.success) {
       $('.msg').html('Success: ' + data.msg);
    } else {
       $('.msg').html('Failed: ' + data.msg);
    }
}, "json");
```

**deleteThis.php**

```
$success = false;
$msg = '';
if(isset($_POST['oid'])) { 
    //delete $_POST['oid'] here        
    $success = true; //if successfull
    $msg = 'Deleted ok';
} else {
    $msg = 'No ID sent';
}

//send json data back
echo json_encode( array('msg'=>$msg, 'success' => $success) );
```

Comment: To get the result of the get(), pass a success-handler. Here you can update your span.

Comment: @Tom yes u r right ,i need to refresh the page before the actual error message is show, to avoid that i want solution sir

Comment: Thank for response . but I don't want alert message, i just want to show a message on page, that's why i use session, bcoz that message comes with a style embedded on span tag, please see the main.php code

Comment: @I Like PHP: That was just an example to demonstrate how it might work. I updated again. You'll need to change the PHP so `<span class="msg"></span>` is always on the page.

Comment: I did this i use this one
`$('#suxes').addClass('msg').html('Success:'+data.msg).fadeOut(3000);`